# How to check if an object==this in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I have spent a great deal of time programming in Java and a decent amount of time writing c++, but I have run into an issue I haven't been able to solve. In a Java class I can simply write the following,

```
public void doOperation(object a)
{
    if(a != this)
    {
        set(a); // just some method that sets this.a = object.a
    }

    doOperation();
}

public void doOperation()
{
   this.a = pow(this.a,3);
}
```

The part I am having trouble implementing in c++ is the if statement where I check if the argument object is equal to this. I have tried this in c++

```cpp
object::doOperation(object a)
{
    if(a != this)
    {
        set(a);
    }

    doOperation();
}

object::doOperation()
{
    this->a = pow(this->a,3)
}
```

The error I get reads, "no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘object’ and ‘object* const’)". Thanks in advance for anybody who can help!

Comment: In that particular code, `a` will never be `this` since it is passed by value (which means a copy is made). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: And even if `&a == this` (for example if you passed `a` by reference), the check would be pointless because doing `this->a = this->a` is a harmless no-op that is cheaper than the check (assuming `a` is a number type).  But guarding against self-assignment can be important in resource-owning types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply pass "a" by reference, take a pointer to "a" and compare it with "this", like so:

```
object::doOperation(object & a)
{
    if(&a != this)
    {
        set(a);
    }

    doOperation();
}

object::doOperation()
{
    this->a = pow(this->a,3)
}
```

This is a standard way that people would e.g. implement copy assignment operators in C++. It's not always done this way, but often the implementation of that will take a const reference to an object, and use a check against "this" to prevent self assignment.

Edit: Let me try to take a broader view, which might be more useful to you.

In Java, objects are implicitly passed around by reference and not by value, and they are garbage collected also, automatically destroyed when no-one needs them anymore.

The closest way to get that kind of semantics in C++ is to pass around `std::shared_ptr<A>` when in java you would have passed `A`. Then, when you need to compare against `this`, you can use the `get` method to get a raw pointer from the shared pointer and compare it literally against this. OR, if you use the `std::enable_shared_from_this` template when you define your class, you can use `shared_from_this` to get a `shared_ptr<A>` to this at any point in your member functions, and compare the shared_ptr's directly.

I'm assuming you are using C++11, otherwise you would use boost headers for that stuff.

Note also the stuff about "weak_ptr" which you might need to use if you have cyclic references.

Comment: `a` will never be equal to `this` since it is passed by value.

Comment: this is true, presumably he should pass it by reference though and isn't used to that because of java

Comment: So maybe you could explain that to him in your answer :)

Comment: Hmm, going from “here is a solution for a problem you don't have” to “here is a way to create a problem you've needlessly solved”. I think @JonathanPotter is right that it is not clear what the OP is trying to accomplish so it's almost impossible to offer substantial help.

Comment: `a` should be passed by const reference, and it would be less confusing to use a different name for the parameter `a` than the member variable `a`

Comment: Matt: In my answer I originally had it as const &, but then since he's calling "set(a)" and I decided it was ambiguous whether that modifies a, I changed it to a non-const reference. I agree the the thing about member variables is a bit confusing.

Comment: Spot on @ChrisBeck! Sorry if my question was not to clear, but you saw exactly what I was asking and your answer was perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `this` is a pointer type in C++. If your function signature would use a pointer as well, it would work:

```
object::doOperation(object* a)
{
    if(a != this)
    {
        set(a);
    }

    doOperation();
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, raw pointers should be avoided; instead pass by reference or use a smart pointer class.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - Yeah, you're right... trying to keep things simple though. Just enough so that the issue is clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In Java most objects are passed around as *references*. To avoid aliasing problems you may then need to check for reference equality: are these two apparently distinct objects, really distinct, or do the references refer to the same object?

In C++ objects are often passed as values, copying their values. And for *values* it doesn't make sense to check for object identity. E.g. a function argument passed by value, as in your `object::doOperation(object a)` example, will always have an address different from everything else at that point in the program execution (it's freshly allocated).

Still there are some cases where objects are passed by reference (or pointer), and where self-check is appropriate.

For example, a copy assignment operator might go like this:

```
auto My_class::operator=( My_class const& other )
    -> My_class&
{
    if( &other != this )
    {
        values_ = other.values_;    // Avoid this work for self-assign.
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The self-check can also be crucial for correctness, although with use of standard library containers and smart pointers correctness can usually be ensured without any self-check.

Answer (score 0):

If an object has been passed by value as in

```
void object::doSomething(object x)
{
    // whatever
}
```

then it is not necessary to compare with this.  Even of the caller does

```
some_object.doSomething(some_object);
```

the `x` is a temporary copy - i.e. so a different object is guaranteed.

If the argument is passed by reference or argument then remember that `this` is a pointer and not a reference (unlike Java in which those concepts are entwined), for example;

```
void object::doSomething(object *x)
{
     if (this != x)
     {

     }
}
```

and

```
void object::doSomething(object &x)
{
     if (this != &x)
     {

     }
}
```

The latter assumes that `object` does not have an interfering `operator&()`.   If that assumption is invalid then, in C++11 use `addressof(x)` (where `addressof()` is specified in `<memory>`.  Before C++11, the tricks to get address of `x` are a little more indirect (e.g. a sequence of casts).

Personally, I don't do such tests at all.  Instead, I simply do

```
void object::doSomething(object &x)
{
     object temp(x);

      // do things with temp and *this

      std::swap(x, temp);
}
```

which relies on working copy semantics, but also gives more exception safety.   If a class makes the above prohibitive, then that is more usually a problem with class design (better to find another way to avoid the need to compare with this).